# merge two cells and display in Grid.Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid.mvc

I am trying to merge two column values and display in [grid.mvc](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/) . I searched a lot and did not find any solution. So i doubt there is any way to do it.So anyone can tell me is there any way we can merge two columns in grid.mvc ??

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns => { 
     columns.Add(c => c.FirstName).Filterable(true); 
     columns.Add(c => c.LastName).Filterable(true); ); 
}).Sortable(true)
```

Comment: Please show what you've done so far, how this is set up, etc. Please read [help]

Comment: This is what i had..                                           @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
                   {                      
                       columns.Add(c => c.FirstName).Filterable(true);
                       columns.Add(c => c.LastName).Filterable(true);
                      );
                   }).Sortable(true)..............  Anywayz gt the solution by trying diff things myself..

Comment: But Filterable(true) and Sortable(true) did not work for the solution i got... Any help ??!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution by using the following:

```
columns.Add().Titled("Customer").RenderValueAs(c => c.FirstName +" "+ c.LastName);
```

Comment: I also need to filter and sort the "Customer" column.But Filterable(true) and Sortable(true) did not work. Any solution? thanks.

Comment: You may need to bind the column to a value to filter and sort by, notice you are using columns.Add() where the () between add is empty. you could maybe bind this to c.FirstName then just keep the RenderValueAs the same.

Comment: no problem!  Grid.Mvc can be quirky but it gets the job done one way or another.